# child component EventEmitter not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have CreateProjectComponent which is child component I need to close a div in Parent when  closeModal is clicked

#### The template (html):

```
<div (click)="closeModal(true)"></div>
```

#### The component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "th-create-project",
    templateUrl: "create-project.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["create-project.scss"],
    directives: [
        ThAutocomplete,
        MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,
        MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES,
    ],
})

export class CreateProjectComponent  {
    @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    public closeModal(agreed: boolean) {
        console.log("vote() on CHILD")

        this.onVoted.emit(true);
    }
}
```

## The parent component

In the parents component template I have:

```
<div *ngIf="(isNewProjectVisible === true)" (onVoted)="receivedEvent()">
```

and in the parent component ts I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: "projects-component",
    templateUrl: `client/+projects/projects.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ["client/+projects/projects.scss"],
    directives: [ProjectListComponent, SelectListComponent, CreateProjectComponent],
    providers: [ProjectService, StateService, CreateProjectService],
})
export class ProjectsComponent extends MeteorComponent implements OnInit {

    public receivedEvent() {  //This method isn't being triggered!!!
        this.isNewProjectVisible = false;
        console.log("receivedEvent() on PARENT")

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you should use `th-create-project` instead of `div` for the element you are using `onVoted` on:  `<th-create-project *ngIf="isNewProjectVisible" (onVoted)="receivedEvent()"></th-create-project>`

Comment: I'm assuming this is not the entire ProjectsComponent, and that "isNewProjectVisble" is true sometimes. Otherwise the div won't exist ;)

Comment: @MarkRajcok, mark that is the answer if you want please add answer and Ill upvote you ;D, hopefully you can give a bit more info why you knew that was the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `div`, you need to specify the selector of the component you want to use:

```
<th-create-project *ngIf="isNewProjectVisible" (onVoted)="receivedEvent()">
</th-create-project>
```

Note, if you use `div`, Angular will not automatically instantiate an instance of  CreateProjectComponent just because you are using one of its output properties – i.e., just becauase `(onVoted)` is in the parent template.  Nor will Angular automatically instantiate an instance of your CreateProjectComponent because it is listed in the `directives` array.  You have to specify it in your template using the selector, as shown above, in order to get an instance.